# Get access to the form in program - windows forms accessibility object

Tags: c#, winforms

Trying to get the form in program by clicking menu item of an application

Tried this

```
menu = Application.OpenForms.Cast<Form>()...
```

Here, I got my control, then I went into menu items for eg, File > New

```
menu.AccessibilityObject.GetChild(0).GetChild(0).DoDefaultAction(); // void
```

Default action of this control - `menu.AccessibilityObject.GetChild(0).GetChild(0)` - is "press".

So, Calling this

```
menu.AccessibilityObject.GetChild(0).GetChild(0).DoDefaultAction(); // void
```

opens the form in actual application, but then program pauses until I close the form. (Closing the form continues the program execution (debugging) )

I want to execute the program when the form gets opened, I am not able to debug it because the form is opened and when I close it, I am able to debug next.

I want to get in the form and access the controls, Is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you want by following the suggestions in [ask]?

Comment: @Enigmativity, I have updated the question, please let me know if you are still unclear

Comment: It's not clear what *application* is. Your Application, as it looks like, since you have `menu = Application.OpenForms.Cast<Form>()...`. What is the ellipsis hiding here? The way you get to one of the opened Forms' MenuStrip or ContxtMenuStrip components? If this method is supposed to be called from the *outside*, why is it not a `public` method? Why are you trying to invoke it through a sub menu item? What action is triggering `DoDefaultAction()`? Meaning, the actual code the default action (`Click`) is running?

Comment: Application is : Encompass (Ellie mae win app)...

Comment: That's a commercial application. Is it your Application or not? If not, how do you get to it with `Application.OpenForms.Cast<Form>()`?

Comment: @Jimi It is my application, 
ellipsis are just for GetType() of control name `EllieMae.MainUI.MainScreen` and getting the control,
Menu items in encompass are as normal as notepad one - File > New, Open, Save

Comment: All right, then `menu.AccessibilityObject.GetChild(0).GetChild(0).DoDefaultAction();` is triggering, e.g., `File -> New`. What code is run there? If this menu opens a modal Dialog, then code that follows `DoDefaultAction()` will be executed after the Dialog is closed. Is this your scenario? Where/when is the code that call `menu = Application.OpenForms[...]` executed?

Comment: @Jimi, `DoDefaultAction()` performs the default action of the control, and it is "Press" for my control, So calling `DoDefaultAction()` presses the menu item and form gets opened

Comment: That's not the question. As already in my first comment, that's the obvious action. But then, this Action, what code is running? Does it show a modal Dialog? If *Yes*, then read what's in my previous comment, otherwise, explain what's happening.

Comment: @Jimi, I want the form which contains the useful information about users, and that form gets opened in Encompass application once I call `DoDefaultAction()`, but then I lose my debugging, and once I close the form, I can debug the next line of code

Comment: @Jimi, It is void action, It opens the form in application but I am not able to get either the form (in program) or continue the debugging while the form is opened

Comment: It doesn't matter whether `DoDefaultAction()` is a void method. What matters is what code is run after the action of a Control/component it triggered. Yours, apparently, causes a Dialog to show up. So, code execution continues only when the Dialog is closed. You could run that action from a Task and invoke the UI thread to open the Dialog, then invoke again to access it, but you're providing very little information on the context of your operations. It's also not clear why do you have to access this dialog to get info on users. If it's for testing, use UI Automation from the outside.